# Raspberry pi can't ping laptop but laptop can ping Raspberry pi

Tags: windows, ssh, raspberry-pi, ntp

Here's the context to my situation. I'm attempting to setup my rpi zero to use my windows laptop as an NTP server. I have all of the configurations done on both my pi and my windows machine to accomplish this. You can imagine my disappointment and frustration when after everything had been said and done it simply didn't work. I commenced to troubleshooting where after much head scratching and misery I discovered the issue (at least I think I did) the NTP client fails to reach the destination host 10.1.1.1 (my pc) and when I try to ping the pc from the terminal I also get the same error.

Here's the weird part though. I can ping the rpi from my pc and can even ssh into it from my pc. When I attempt to resolve the host from my pc using ping pi.local it returns the ipv6 address of the pi. I can ping both the ipv4 and ipv6 address of pi from pc but can not ping ipv4 or ipv6 of pc from the pi. The pi is using usb0 as network interface with

```
    iface usb0 inet static
         address 10.1.1.2
         netmask 255.255.255.0
         gateway 10.1.1.1
    allow-hotplug usb0
```

When I run ifconfig it shows the correct address on usb0 and I can ping it from pc. Why can't I ping the pc from pi? I'm fairly certain that this is the root of my problem with the NTP client communication error that I'm getting but for the life of me I can't figure out why it won't communicate i.e ping the pc from the pi.

Comment: Why do you have the gateway and your PC set to the same address?

Comment: The PC is the gateway for this pi

Answer (score 2):

"By default, a new Windows 10 installation will have the firewall enabled and set to not respond to ICMP pings, even from hosts on a private network. This can resolved enabling the correct whitelist entries in the firewall."
[Source](http://aaronmanvell.com/2016/01/windows-10-does-not-respond-to-ping/)